# Why does the variable changed during recursion (trying to calculate matrix determinant)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, matrix

I'm trying to calculate the determinant of a matrix (row-major order) using simple recursion, but for some reason the variable `matrix` changed during the last loop, and I don't understand why because I didn't write any code that changed the value of the variable at all.

```
import math
def print_m(matrix):  # Print the matrix
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        print(matrix[i])

def determinant(matrix):# return determinant assuming scanning through first row
    if len(matrix[0]) != len(matrix):
        print('Not square matrix')
        return None

    if len(matrix) == 2:
        print('LAST STEP EXECUTED')
        return matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1] - matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0]

    def get_reduced_matrix(matrix, column):  #not responsible for changin sign
        newM = matrix[1:]
        for i in range(len(matrix) - 1):
            del newM[i][column]
        return newM

    output = 0
    for i in range(len(matrix)): #value of matrix changed when i turned into 1
        print("i =", i)
        print_m(matrix)
        print('END')
        output += matrix[0][i] * determinant(get_reduced_matrix(matrix, i)) * math.pow(-1, i + 1)  # change in sign at last
        print('Gonna do the loop again')
    return output



matrix1 = [
    [11, 12, 13],
    [21, 22, 23],
    [31, 32, 33]
]

print(determinant(matrix1))
```

output:

```
C:\Users\jason\Desktop\Python\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/jason/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/sdf.py
i = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jason/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/sdf.py", line 38, in <module>
[11, 12, 13]
    print(determinant(matrix1))
[21, 22, 23]
[31, 32, 33]
  File "C:/Users/jason/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/sdf.py", line 26, in determinant
end
    output += matrix[0][i] * determinant(get_reduced_matrix(matrix, i)) * math.pow(-1, i + 1)  # change in sign at last
LAST STEP EXECUTED
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType' #MATRIX LOST SOME OF ITS VALUE HERE
gonna do the loop again
i = 1
[11, 12, 13]
[22, 23]
[32, 33]
end
Not square matrix

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So matrix just lost its first column entry in 2nd and 3rd row, and I don't know what happened at all. Like I said, I didn't write any code that can change the `matrix` value in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is changing is because a matrix holds references to the arrays that make up the rows.

If you have a matrix:

```
matrix1 = [
  [11, 12, 13],
  [21, 22, 23],
  [31, 32, 33]
]
```

and you take a slice with:

```
newM = matrix[1:]
```

`newM` is a new matrix but it holds references to the same row arrays as the original matrix:

```
>> newM = matrix[1:]
>> newM[0] is matrix[1] # is it the same reference

True
```

You will need to make a deeper copy of the rows if you want to manipulate them without changing the original. Maybe something like :

```
newM = [m[:] for m in matrix[1:]]
```

would work in the case?

Comment: `copy.deepcopy(matrix[1:])` also works. (I mention this because it can help in other situation, and I find this more explicit and readable).